# How to do gitversion in Gitlab CI with docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have this in my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"

determine version:
  stage: preparation
  tags: 
    - docker
  image: gittools/gitversion
  script:
    - pwd
    - echo $(pwd)
    - gitversion /output json /showvariable FullSemVer > version.txt
    - cat version.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - version.txt
    expire_in: 1 hr
```

When this runs on my runner, I get this:

```
1 Running with gitlab-runner 12.6.0 (ac8e767a)
2   on gitlab-runner-01 efEDOrEf
3
Using Docker executor with image gittools/gitversion ...
4 Pulling docker image gittools/gitversion ...
5 Using docker image sha256:2d1d36c0807eaeedc8d4a81b72ae3ee16f7c6a1d25bdce22c8e1983ac6c98dcb for gittools/gitversion ...
7
Running on runner-efEDOrEf-project-475-concurrent-0 via gitlab-runner-01...
9
Fetching changes...
10 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/applications/myapplicationname/.git/
11 From https://path/to/my/git
12  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/10548 -> refs/pipelines/10548
13    638ed79..9c57f34  feature/3442   -> origin/feature/3442
14 Checking out 9c57f347 as feature/3442...
15 Skipping Git submodules setup
19
INFO [01/10/20 16:05:44:94] Applicable build agent found: 'GitLabCi'.WARN [01/10/20 16:05:44:95] The working directory 'sh' does not exist.INFO [01/10/20 16:05:44:95] IsDynamicGitRepository: FalseERROR [01/10/20 16:05:44:97] An unexpected error occurred:
20 System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Can't find the .git directory in 
21    at GitVersion.GitPreparer.GetProjectRootDirectoryInternal() in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionCore\GitPreparer.cs:line 92
22    at GitVersion.GitPreparer.GetProjectRootDirectory() in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionCore\GitPreparer.cs:line 27
23    at GitVersion.Configuration.ConfigFileLocator.Verify(IGitPreparer gitPreparer) in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionCore\Configuration\ConfigFileLocator.cs:line 61
24    at GitVersion.GitVersionExecutor.VerifyArgumentsAndRun(Arguments arguments) in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionExe\GitVersionExecutor.cs:line 105INFO [01/10/20 16:05:44:97] INFO [01/10/20 16:05:44:97] Attempting to show the current git graph (please include in issue): INFO [01/10/20 16:05:44:97] Showing max of 100 commits
26
INFO [01/10/20 16:05:46:26] Applicable build agent found: 'GitLabCi'.WARN [01/10/20 16:05:46:26] The working directory 'sh' does not exist.INFO [01/10/20 16:05:46:26] IsDynamicGitRepository: FalseERROR [01/10/20 16:05:46:28] An unexpected error occurred:
27 System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Can't find the .git directory in 
28    at GitVersion.GitPreparer.GetProjectRootDirectoryInternal() in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionCore\GitPreparer.cs:line 92
29    at GitVersion.GitPreparer.GetProjectRootDirectory() in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionCore\GitPreparer.cs:line 27
30    at GitVersion.Configuration.ConfigFileLocator.Verify(IGitPreparer gitPreparer) in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionCore\Configuration\ConfigFileLocator.cs:line 61
31    at GitVersion.GitVersionExecutor.VerifyArgumentsAndRun(Arguments arguments) in D:\a\1\s\src\GitVersionExe\GitVersionExecutor.cs:line 105INFO [01/10/20 16:05:46:28] INFO [01/10/20 16:05:46:28] Attempting to show the current git graph (please include in issue): INFO [01/10/20 16:05:46:28] Showing max of 100 commits
34
Uploading artifacts...
35 WARNING: version.txt: no matching files            
36 ERROR: No files to upload                          
38 Job succeeded
```

How can I get Gitversion to determine the version for my build?
I use it for all code that's not built using Docker and I could use that, but I feel it should work in a container as well.

Also, both `pwd` and `echo $(pwd)` do not show up in the output, how can I get something in the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> both `pwd` and `echo $(pwd)` do not show up in the output,

This comes from the fact no command is actually executed inside the container, because this image [`gittools/gitversion`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/gittools/gitversion/latest/images/sha256-9d9801b4e96acfd7f205559a6a619c0cda2d794b890674c278a6d80a3cf5b12f) contains the following **entrypoint**:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/GitVersion.dll"]
```

which is compatible with the one-liner suggested in https://hub.docker.com/r/gittools/gitversion:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" gittools/gitversion:latest-linux-netcoreapp2.2 /repo
```

which fails when no command-line argument is provided, and thereby fails with the `docker exec`-implied use of GitLab CI.

Moreover, it seems the image doesn't support the `gitversion` command but rather `dotnet /app/GitVersion.dll`.

#### Solution 1

As a workaround, you may want to override the entrypoint and try:

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"

determine version:
  stage: preparation
  tags: 
    - docker
  image:
    name: gittools/gitversion
    entrypoint: /bin/bash

  script:
    - pwd
    - dotnet /app/GitVersion.dll /output json /showvariable FullSemVer > version.txt
    - cat version.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - version.txt
    expire_in: 1 hr
```

#### Solution 2

Use a handcrafted `docker run` command, [using **Docker-in-Docker**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#container-registry-examples) (`dind`):

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"

determine-version:
  stage: preparation
  tags: 
    - docker
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind

  script:
    - pwd
    - docker run --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" gittools/gitversion:latest-linux-netcoreapp2.2 /repo /output json /showvariable FullSemVer > version.txt
    - cat version.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - version.txt
    expire_in: 1 hr
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that when I get in the office on Monday. In the mean time, is this actually the preferred way of using a tool like Gitversion, or would it make more sense to do an 'apt install gitversion' on the host container?

Comment: I guess if you install the `gitversion` package on the host server that runs the Docker executor, it won't be available from the CI job script (due to Docker's isolation). However instead of applying the "Solution 1" as is, I think you could just as well build and use another image in place of of `gittools/gitversion`, containing `gitversion` installed with `apt`…

Comment: The second option actually seems the proper way to me (as it also uses the command as proposed by gitversion's site).
But ... it complains it cannot find any branches on the repo, It sees the repo, but cannot see any commits related to the branches. It works on my machine, so it seems that gitlab-ci does not do a proper 'fetch' before beginning. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The way the repo is cloned before running the CI script is governed by several vars, e.g. [GIT_STRATEGY](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#git-strategy) (`none` skipping the clone) & [GIT_DEPTH](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#shallow-cloning). And [the default value of `GIT_DEPTH` recently changed to 50](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/merge_requests/28919) so GitLab CI makes *shallow clones*, without all branches. To avoid this you can just add `variables:\n GIT_DEPTH: 0` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, or put 0 as default value in `https://gitlab.com/username/reponame/-/settings/ci_cd`

Answer (score 1):

At least as of GitLab version 13.10 and GitVersion 5.6.11, the following can be used to add the version to a variable. In this example I use the `"SemVer"` output, but this can easily be changed.

```
Determine version:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gittools/gitversion:5.6.11-debian.10-x64
    entrypoint: ['']
  script: |
    echo "VERSION=$(/tools/dotnet-gitversion | sed --silent --regexp-extended 's/^\s*"SemVer": "([^"]+)".*$/\1/p')" >> build.env
    cat build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

Publish package:
  stage: deploy
  script: |
    echo "We have a ${VERSION} we can use!"
```

I adapted the above from the [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job).

Comment: You may want to add some link to the official documentation, e.g. [this one](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job)?

Comment: BTW, a `dependencies:` or `needs:` keyword seems necessary, according to the doc?

Comment: Nope, `dependencies:` is not needed. By default artifacts are applied to all downstream jobs unless explicitly specified via `dependencies:`. I don't need the `needs` because they're in separate stages (build and deploy). The documentation is a bit confusing because they name their jobs the same name as their stages. XD